# How to store User Data in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can anyone please let me know how to store logged in user data into global scope of AngularJS,

My Login services is looked like this

```
App.service('Auth', function($http){
    return {
        isLogin:function(callback){
            $http.get('api/auth/checkLogin').success(function(res){
                callback(res);
            });
        },
        login:function(user, callback){
            $http.post('api/auth/login', user).success(function(res){
                callback(res);
            });
        },
        logout:function(callback){
            $http.get('api/auth/logout').success(function(res){
                callback(res);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I'm using the same in my controller like this

```
$scope.isLogin = false;
$scope.UserData = {};
$scope.login = function(user){
    Auth.login(user, function(res){
        if(res.status){
            $scope.isLogin = true;
            $scope.loginBoxShown = false;
            $scope.UserData = res.data;
            $location.path('/Dashboard');
        }
    });
};
```

Its working fine on first run but once I reload the page the variable `$scope.isLogin` and `$scope.UserData` are reset to their default value.

Is there any way to store them in a global scope permanently before my `$scope.logout();` function delete them.

Comment: why don't you try using a cookie, and put a hashed key on it?

Answer (score 3):

I normally use ngStorage for user data persistence. Found at https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

> An AngularJS module that makes Web Storage working in the Angular Way. Contains two services: $localStorage and $sessionStorage.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

The question isn't really Angular specific. To persist data across page reloads you basically have two options `localStorage` (and it's little sister `sessionStorage`) or `cookies`.

Both techniques are [covered in other SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage) already.

Comment: The idea might not be Angular specific, but the question most certainly is!

Comment: Yep, just like *"How do I add two numbers in jQuery"* ;-)